# Typescript Array Syntax MyModel[] or [MyModel]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a a UserModel as shown below.

```
export class UserModel {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public firstName: string,
        public lastName: string
    ) { }
}
```

If I want an array of Users that complies to UserModel, do I use

```
var userArray: UserModel[] = []
```

or

```
var userArray: [UserModel] = [];
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Extra TIP :- In typescript use `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) we can see that an array is declared as either

```
let userArray: UserModel[] = [];
```

or

```
let userArray: Array<UserModel> = [];
```

And that a `Tuple` is declared as

```
let x: [string, number];
```

As such, your second statement does not declare an array at all.